# How to use QImage repeatedly?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have a horizontal sprite of images. This one for example:

[image]

All the images have the same width and height. I have stored it in my resources file, and declared it in my application by a *define*:

```
#define SPRITE QImage(":/sprite.png")
```

So there are 4 images that I will need several times in my application. In order to do this, I implemented this function which retrieves the image at the position *n* in the sprite.

```
QImage getNthImageFromSprite(int n, QImage sprite)
{
    int size = sprite.height();
    return sprite.copy((n - 1) * size, 0, size, size);
}
```

Then, I declared a general enum to put names on the position:

```
enum eImage
{
    eImage_black = 1,
    eImage_red,
    eImage_orange,
    eImage_green
}
```

And finally, the function that I'm using anywhere in my application:

```
QImage getSpriteImage(eImage img)
{
    return getNthImageFromSprite(img, SPRITE);
}
```

**This works well**.

But I have the impression that this is not very good, since I call the constructor of `QImage` each time I want to get a specific image. Knowing that a sprite can contain +40 images and that I will need these images several times, should I cache an image the first time it get called, or the way I'm doing it is good?

---

*Note: I need QImage for various reasons, but a comparison with QPixmap would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the define with an object:

```
static QImage SPRITE(":/sprite.png");
```

It will be initialized only once on startup.

You can even put it in the method:

```
QImage getSpriteImage(eImage img)
{
    static QImage SPRITE(":/sprite.png");
    return getNthImageFromSprite(img, SPRITE);
}
```

In this case, it is initialized on first usage.

Howerver, you sill create new objects for every call to `getNthSpriteImage`. You could use a local static cache to re-use already returned objects:

```
QImage getNthSpriteImage(int n, QImage img) {
    static QMap<int, QImage> cache;
    if (!cache.contains(n)) {
        int size = sprite.height();
        cache[n] = sprite.copy((n - 1) * size, 0, size, size);
    }
    return cache[n];
}
```

---

As for the difference for QImage/QPixmap, this is the main difference:

> QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and for direct pixel access and manipulation, while QPixmap is designed and optimized for showing images on screen.

So I would recommend to use QPixmap if you don't want special image formats (RGBA, premultiplied RGBA, indexed, ...) or use direct pixel manipulation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using pixel manipulation after this. But great answer! I don't know how I didn't think about the *static* for the sprite, shame on me... And thanks for the cache solution!