# Is it possible to use only a portion of QImage for styling?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Let's take the horizontal sprite of images of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698053/how-to-use-qimage-repeatedly):

[image]

So, I have 4 images in 1. Let's say that I want to use only the green circle for styling a QComboBox arrow. I know I can style it with a single image with

```
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/downarrow.png);
}
```

but is it possible (in the stylesheet or by another means) to get only a piece of the image used?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possibile with Qt Style Sheets, since they do not support absolute values for **background-position**, as stated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#background-image-prop)

The answer to the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698053/how-to-use-qimage-repeatedly) is still the best way to implement this with Qt.

Comment: Your link to my question doesn't really give an answer: since I retrieve a QImage anyway, how can I put this QImage in the stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood your question. I believed you were asking for a stylesheet based method as an alternative to your getNthImageFromSprite() method to extract only one of the 4 circles. As I said, this is not possible with Qt Style Sheets. Since you state you have this file stored in your embedded resources, why don't you simply store **4** different files instead?

Comment: S. Monteleone: I could (and I know how to do it), but the idea is to store all my images in a single sprite.

Comment: @IAmInPLS then you have two possible routes: derive your custom widget from QComboBox and reimplement the painting there or write your own QStyle and override the drawControl() method to handle this particular case.

Comment: definitely, I was just trying to see if there was an easier method :-)